# Как округлять в большую сторону до половины или до целого числа JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, округление

Есть код, не важно какой, суть в чем: при делении получается число равное площади используемой для изделия из плит, которые продаются либо целые либо пополам, и если получилось число 1 < x < 1.5 (например) то округлять до 1.5, а если 1.5 < x < 2 то к 2, как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Округляем в большую сторону число умноженное на 2 и делим на 2

```js
var number = 1.4;

console.log(Math.ceil(number*2)/2);

var number = 1.7;

console.log(Math.ceil(number*2)/2);
```

Comment: круто, спасибо)